# How to identify a broadcasted intent uniquely

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

In my app i have to receive USER_PRESENT and AIRPLANE_MODE intents. But each intent is broadcasted twice (sometimes thrice) which i don't want. I was trying to resolve this issue using SharedPreferences but i need to identify each intent uniquely (with any 'id' if it has or timestamp etc).

The following is the code where i was trying to allow only one onReceive call.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

final SharedPreferences instanceCount = context.getSharedPreferences("Instances",Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE); 
   SharedPreferences.Editor instance_editor = instanceCount.edit();
    if(instanceCount.getBoolean("instance",true))
    {
        instance_editor.putBoolean("instance",false);
        instance_editor.commit();
    }
    else
    {
        instance_editor.putBoolean("instance",true);
        instance_editor.commit();
        return;
    } 
                          .
                          .
                          .
                          .
}
```

Can any one please help in solving this. Thank You :)

Answer (score 0):

Those are system broadcasts and you cannot control how many times they are broadcasted. Make your receiver(s) idempotent, e.g., it stays in the same state even if it is invoke multiple times. Instead of counting broadcasts, save the current state of your app and check it when you receive a broadcast. If you are already in the desired state, do nothing. Otherwise, change the state as appropriate and save it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But in my receiver i'm sending an sms to some number and it is sending sms twice or thrice each time. For that i  cannot save the state. And i don't understand why android will not send intent only once.

Comment: Of course you can: save how many times you have sent an SMS to particular number and react accordingly.

Comment: If i save the sms sent count it goes to the same above problem.. I mean the problem comes when i want to reset the count(to start the count again when i receive intent).

Comment: Then save a timestamp as well, etc. It all depends on your apps' logic, trying to depend on system implementation details (how may times the intent is sent) is the wrong approach.

Comment: timestamps are same most of the times.